# New Bee with Python to Exe issue

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using python and am trying to convert into an `.exe`. The runtime version works great without errors. Once I try to compile with pyinstaller, I get an executable that doesn't work. Pyinstaller produces [warning messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/steUU.png).

Answer (score 1):

I went back to python3.6, that fixed the issues with pyinstaller !